# Aggregate on dictionary question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, aggregate

I am using ASP.NET MVC2 and I would like to make up a url based on the current one in the address bar inside a HtmlHelper extension. So far I have this:

```
url = helper.ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values
      .Aggregate<KeyValuePair<String, Object>>((w, next) => w +  next);
```

But that does not compile. Anyone has a good idea on how to solve this Aggregate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
helper.ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values
                .Select(x => x.Value.ToString())
                .Aggregate((c, next) => c + next);
```

But since you want something like a url I suggest you use this:

```
helper.ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values
                .Select(x => x.Value.ToString())
                .Aggregate((c, next) => c + "/" + next);
```

Grz, Kris.