# How to get current route in HtmlHelper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

A followup question to: [Aggregate on dictionary question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091705/aggregate-on-dictionary-question).

I used the Aggregate Linq functionality but perhaps there is a better, more clean way, to do it?

Can I get the current route from the HtmlHelper? Or what do you suggest? I want to make a language switcher so as when I am on a page/route and click another language the same action gets requested but with another language in the route.

Something like

**EN/Home/Index** and **FR/Home/Index**

Answer (score 10):

You can easily retrieve the current route, or pieces of it. Assuming an HtmlHelper is your context as you say, it should look something like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString SomeHelper(this HtmlHelper html) {
    RouteBase route = html.ViewContext.RouteData.Route;
    string action = html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    string controller = html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    // ...
}
```